# Does FD_ISSET() return the file descriptor which received data

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets, select

I have the following code

```
fd = listen_socket(INADDR_ANY, CLIENT_PORT, client_config.interface);
fdr = raw_socket(client_config.ifindex);
if (fd >= 0) FD_SET(fd, &rfds);
if (fdr >= 0) FD_SET(fdr, &rfds);

max_fd = fd > fdr ? fd : fdr;
retval = select(max_fd + 1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);

if (FD_ISSET(fd, &rfds)) {
    ....
} else if (FD_ISSET(fdr, &rfds)) {
    ....
}
```

If we receive data from the `fd` socket, does the `FD_ISSET(fd, &rfds)` returns true and `FD_ISSET(fdr, &rfds)` returns false?

Comment: Try it and find out??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [POSIX standards reference page on `select`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pselect.html):

> `FD_ISSET(fd, fdsetp)` shall evaluate to non-zero if the file descriptor fd is a member of the set pointed to by fdsetp, and shall evaluate to zero otherwise.

So exactly *what* the result of `FD_ISSET` (which is really not a function but a macro so technically it doesn't "return" anything) is not mentioned, just that it's either zero or non-zero.

To answer your question, yes. If `fd` is readable then `FD_ISSET(fd, &rfds)` will be non-zero (true) and `FD_ISSET(fdr, &rfds)` will be zero (false) (unless it's *also* readable, so don't use `else if` there, both might be true).

Comment: so the FD_ISSET result depend to the select function

Comment: @MOHAMED Yes, the `select` function modifies the sets passed to it. That's why, if you call `select` in a loop, you should always re-initialize the sets before each call.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. That is its purpose. Read the documentation.